# Pipe Ubuntu Sound Output To Mac

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, audio, ubuntu-10.04, redirection

I am running ubuntu 10.04 and would like to redirect all the sound it outputs to my mac over the network. Is there any way to do this? I would like to hear sound from the mac as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several so-called sound servers that can forward sound from one machine to another. Each has its own protocol, so you need matching programs on both machines.

- On Ubuntu, the default sound server is PulseAudio, which unfortunately doesn't work on MacOS.
- Esound exists on both sides. To hear Ubuntu programs on the Mac loudspeakers, run an esound server on the Mac and set up the esound sink in the Ubuntu pulseaudio configuration. For the other way round, these links may help:

  - https://labitat.dk/index.php/Apple/Mac_OS_X#PulseAudio
  - http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060602065532384
- Jack exists on both sides; the [Jack FAQ](http://jackaudio.org/faq) has relevant information.

I've never done this with a Mac involved, so actual experience reports would be welcome if you try these suggestions. In particular, some configurations may work but have noticeable latency, which is a problem for some uses.

Comment: Thanks for tipping me off to esound. Found a solution here: http://community.livejournal.com/evan_tech/241887.html